# Identify film with women-only world, that has a man released into it

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, post-apocalyptic

Film, perhaps for TV.  US.  C. 2000ish (wide error bars).

The world has only females and they live a pastoral, rural life.  Maybe the men died in a plague, don't remember.  They release one man from some cryo chamber or the like (don't recall).  He interacts with the women and eventually brings strife.  They lock him back in the chamber, and the old female leader says goodbye *his name*...and the man realizes she was actually his old love, grown old.

The male actor looked like David Keith.

Comment: My first guess was Polish Sexmission (1984) https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088083/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is **"[Lithia](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667918/)"** (1998), S04E17 of the 1995-2002 revival of *[The Outer Limits](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112111/)*.

> **Major Jason Mercer awakes from a cryogenics experiment to a primitive Earth society devoid of men. His presence among these women, many of whom have never seen a man, begins to complicate the relationships of the colony, with disastrous results.**

From [The Outer Limits Wiki](https://theouterlimits.fandom.com/wiki/Lithia):

> "Lithia" is set in 2055, in a world populated only by women. A man **(David Keith)** who is cryogenically frozen, however, wakes up and enters one of their communities. They explain to him almost all the previous population was killed years earlier in a war, followed by a plague that killed the remaining men (since it solely affected them). Since then, they reproduced with artificial insemination. However, the virus still exists, and kills male babies within days or at most weeks.
>
> The women are living in a commune, and seem to be living full and happy lives, although they must work very hard, lacking some of the technology of the past. Neighboring villages have many of the resources, all in control of a council governing their use and trade. When a neighboring village refuses to defy the council and trade electricity prior to completion of an impact study, Mercer tells the women living in his commune that they must make sure that they have enough resources for themselves. Their leader tells him that kind of thinking is what led to war, she being the only woman old enough to remember. Intrigued by her memory, children ask her to tell of the man she loved before the war.
>
> Mercer becomes aggressive and proceeds to steal electricity from a rival village, enlisting help from a woman he becomes romantically involved with. Unfortunately, this leads to the deaths of several different women when the other village first tries to stop him, then tries to get the better of a prisoner trade with the woman who helped Mercer. After the funeral of the women from the village, it is revealed that the council was responsible for unfreezing eleven other men and attempting to integrate them into their society, but each attempt resulted in a similar tragedy. **Moments before Mercer is refrozen, Hera (Julie Harris), the leader of Lithia, calls him by his first name, Jason. Pleading for his life as he is about to be refrozen, Mercer is confused as to how she would know that, but, as she looks at her locket containing a picture of Mercer, we realize that he is the same Jason whom she loved before he was initially frozen during the war.**

As noted in the The Outer Limits Wiki plot summary above and the [IMDB credits for the episode](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667918/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_1), the actor playing the man (Major Jason Mercer) actually is David Keith.

[image: Image of David Keith from S04E17 of "The Outer Limits" (1995-2002).]

Comment: Does the actor look like David Keith?

Comment: @Valorum - The actor playing the man literally _is_ David Keith, as mentioned in the first section of bolded text.

Comment: So you're saying that he does look like David Keith then?

Comment: @Valorum - The resemblance is uncanny.

Comment: You rock!  Thanks, man.  Perfectamundo.

Comment: I momentarily confused David Keith with [Keith David](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_David) and I was very confused.

Comment: @LogicDictates He's a method actor, really inhabiting his role.